# Phpbb new successful member registration pop up window

Tags: phpbb

I would like to create a pop up welcome message for the new member that's  successfully registered.

But I m having problem of finding where should I put the code, I have check the ucp_register.html ,, but I don't think that is the display content after the member successfully registered, can anyone help me please? Thanks

Comment: When a user registers, iirc they view output from trigger_error(). The template file that is ouput by that function is message_body.html iirc, but since it's used elsewhere you'll need to check to make sure they're in the registration module before you display the popup. The same would be true if you were wanting to display something after they activate their account.

Comment: Why not use jQuery UI dialog to accomplish this. You can always wrap script tags inside the trigger_error() e.g `$message = '<script>jQuery("document").ready(function(){jQuery("#mydialog").dialog("open")});setTimeout(function(){jQuery("#mydialog").fadeOut();window.location.href="index.php";}, 5000);</script>'; trigger_error($message);` and in overall_header.html have  `<div id="mydialog" style="display:none">Thanks for the registration</div>`

Answer (score 0):

It would likely to be a more robust solution to display the popup on the first time the user is logged in as an activated user -- after registration they may not be activated, or they may close the browser window immediately after registration.

The way to do this would be to add a column (say, `user_JBL_seen_message INT` to the `phpbb_users` table in the database, then modify functions.php to check that column:

In functions.php, find:

```
// The following assigns all _common_ variables that may be used at any point in a template.
```

Before, add:

```
if($user->data['is_registered'] && $user->data['is_active'] && !$user->data['is_bot'])
{
    if(isset($user->data['user_JBL_seen_message']) && !$user->data['user_JBL_seen_message'])) 
    {
        $showPopup = true;
        $sql = 'UPDATE ' . USERS_TABLE . ' SET user_JBL_seen_message = 1 
          WHERE user_id = ' . (int)$user->data['user_id'];
        if (!$result = $db->sql_query($sql)) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, find:

```
$template->assign_vars(array(
```

After, add:

```
'JBL_POPUP'        => $showPopup,
```

Then, you can add the popup HTML code to your overall_header.html template file, where appropriate...

```
<!-- IF JBL_POPUP -->
    .... your HTML popup code here.....

<!-- END IF -->
```

If you don't want existing users to see the popup, then fill the new column with 1s.

I also agree with Damien's suggestion to use a jQuery UI dialog rather than a popup -- most users' browsers will block popups. However, use jQuery in noconflict mode to avoid conflicts with other mods.